# I am not able to move my sprite around in my pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In this code, I am starting out by trying to make a sprite named "player" move across the screen. It does not move at all. I looked at other questions regarding the same problem, but they mostly had problems that were because of things like not doing a main loop. Here is the code.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect()
player = Player()

def update(self, pressed_keys):
    if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
    if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
        self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
        self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((200,200,200))

    screen.blit(player.surf, (display_height/6, display_width/2))

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: is the "update" function indented properly? seems like its outside of the player class

Comment: With `screen.blit(player.surf, (display_height/6, display_width/2))` you always paint the sprite at the same position.

Comment: If it is outside of the player class, what would be the problem?

Comment: @RhinoRunner You would call the default implementation of `update` and that [does nothing](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.update).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update` is a method of `Player`. Fix the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). Create the instance of `palyer` after the class.

You have to draw the player at `player.rect` rather than `(display_height/6, display_width/2)`:

<s>`screen.blit(player.surf, (display_height/6, display_width/2))`</s>

```py
screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)
```

`(display_height/6, display_width/2)` is the intitial position of the palyer:

```py
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        # [...]

        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))
```

```py
player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)
```

See the complete example:

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT,
)
print('Use the window above to play')
pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((75, 25))
        self.surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.surf.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def update(self, pressed_keys):
        if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0, 5)
        if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)

player = Player(display_width // 2, display_height // 2)
alive = True
while alive:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        print(event)
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            alive = False

    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.update(pressed_keys)

    screen.fill((200,200,200))

    screen.blit(player.surf, player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```